# Grid element throwing exception on .Children.Add in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml

I'm on a separate thread, and I'm trying to add a child element to a grid (defined in XAML), so my first instinct would be to do this:

```
var someElement = new TextBlock { Text = "Hello world" };
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MainGrid.Children.Add(someElement));
```

But it seems that an exception is being thrown, with the message being "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

I've also tried `MainGrid.Dispatcher.Invoke` and `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke`, but they both throw the same exception.

To try to see what's going on, I've created a TextBlock element (also defined in XAML). I've edited its `Text` property with a simple `Dispatcher.Invoke` call, and that works. What is the reason for this? How can I fix it?

Comment: could you tell me what is your 'someElement'? it's defined in code-behind? or xaml?

Comment: `someElement` would be an element created through the code-behind before the Invoke. I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: I've tried like your code, but it worked normal. could you try this: this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { MainGrid.Children.Add(new TextBlock(){Text = "Hello World"}); }));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are trying to create the TextBlock on the wrong thread? Does this work:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{ 
    var someElement = new TextBlock { Text = "Hello world" };
    MainGrid.Children.Add(someElement)
});
```

Comment: Yes, this was the issue! In the code I posted originally, I created the TextBlock on a separate thread. After creating the TextBlock through Dispatcher, everything works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

@Andrew, I also think the problem is in your textblock, please tried this:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { MainGrid.Children.Add(new TextBlock(){Text = "Hello World"}); }));
```